# python pandas percent change with columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started studying pandas and have questions.
Firstly, I'd like to ask this.

I have dataframe and it's like below.

```
  Date        Open        High         Low       Close    
2015-11-02  711.059998  721.619995  705.849976  721.109985   
2015-11-03  718.859985  724.650024  714.719971  722.159973   
2015-11-04  722.000000  733.099976  721.900024  728.109985   
2015-11-05  729.469971  739.479980  729.469971  731.250000   
2015-11-06  731.500000  735.409973  727.010010  733.760010
```

I know

```
df["Close"].pct_change()
```

make the percent change from Close to Close.

But,
I want to add a new column, "CloseToOpen" which is a percent change of "yesterday Close to today Open".

So, it is "Open(Day 0) / Close(Day -1) -1".
Of course, the first row should be "NaN" or Zero because there's no "previous day's Close".

How can I make this with python pandas code??

Thanks guys!

This is what I want.

```
Date        Open        High        Low         Close       CloseToOpen
2015-11-02  711.059998  721.619995  705.849976  721.109985  0.000000
2015-11-03  718.859985  724.650024  714.719971  722.159973  -0.003120
2015-11-04  722.000000  733.099976  721.900024  728.109985  -0.000222
2015-11-05  729.469971  739.479980  729.469971  731.250000  0.001868
2015-11-06  731.500000  735.409973  727.010010  733.760010  0.000342
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also you can use standard operands to achieve what you wanted:

```
df['CloseToOpen'] = (df['Open'] / df['Close'].shift(1) - 1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: eh? would you elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
df['CloseToOpen'] = df['Open'].sub(df['Close'].shift()).div(df['Close'] - 1).fillna(0)
print (df)
                  Open        High         Low       Close  CloseToOpen
Date                                                                   
2015-11-02  711.059998  721.619995  705.849976  721.109985     0.000000
2015-11-03  718.859985  724.650024  714.719971  722.159973    -0.003120
2015-11-04  722.000000  733.099976  721.900024  728.109985    -0.000220
2015-11-05  729.469971  739.479980  729.469971  731.250000     0.001862
2015-11-06  731.500000  735.409973  727.010010  733.760010     0.000341
```